# SQLite query with two tables to find the "next episode to watch"

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I have two tables, one is for TV Shows and the other for Episodes, schematically:

```
show {
  long id;
  String title;
}

episode {
 int season;
 int episode;
 long showId (foreign key)
 int watched: Default (0)
}
```

I am trying to run a query that will return for each show, **the next episode the user has to watch**. Let's say I have two shows, Show A and Show B, each line is a season and each number an episode. I am representing the episodes with 0 (not watched) and 1 (watched).

```
A (2 seasons of 4 episodes)
0000
0000

B (3 seasons of 3 episodes)
000
000
000
```

For the previous example, the query should return:

```
A, season = 1, episode = 1
B, season = 1, episode = 1
```

More examples:

```
A
010
000
B
111
000
```

Here the query should return:

```
A, season = 1, episode = 3
B, season = 2, episode = 1
```

Another:

```
A
0100100101
0001000000
B
1110000001
0000000010
```

Here the query should return:

```
A, season = 2, episode = 5
B, season = 2, episode = 10
```

As you can see, user can skip episodes, or watch them without order but I always want to show as "next to watch" the one that is immediately next to the furthest episode watched.

Is it possible to do this in one query? (can have subqueries, of course). But I am looking for one query here so then I can attach it to an Android Loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great task for analytic functions. Unfortunately, however, SQLite lacks analytic functions.

The first step is to find the last seen episode per show. Then from all episodes after that pick the earlist.

An episode consists of two parts actually; the season and the episode number. We'll have to combine them in order to easily compare them. Let's say that three digits for each suffices, then we could make episode 5 of season 2 the string 002005 which comes lexically after any 001xxx and before any 003xxx etc. and also after 002004 and before 002006. A perfect key to get the episodes in order.

So: 1. get max(sortkey) per show, 2. get all episodes after these, 3. get min(sortkey) per show from these episodes, 4. get the records with these sortkeys.

```
with series as
(
  select 
    episode.*,
    substr('000' || season, -3, 3) || substr('000' || episode, -3, 3) as sortkey
  from episode
)
select 
  (select title from show where show.id = series.showid) as show_title,
  series.season, 
  series.episode
from series
join
(
  select showid, min(sortkey) as sortkey
  from series
  where sortkey >
  (
    select coalesce(max(sortkey), '000000')
    from series last_watched
    where last_watched.watched = 1
    and last_watched.showid = series.showid
  )
  group by showid
) next_episode on next_episode.showid = series.showid
               and next_episode.sortkey = series.sortkey;
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. Your explanation makes sense. However, I have been trying to implement it (on my own, based on your explanation and looking at your code) but I didn't get to the result yet. Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27405/42 . Could you take a look into it?

I get Show A, season 2 episode 2 and Show B season 2 episode 2. So yea for show B is using season/episode from Show A :/

Comment: And I think my problem is that the subquery that takes the max(sortkey) is always returning the max of all the table (not per show).

Comment: Well, you made a fiddle with MySQL, which is quite different from SQLite, but anyway, ... Your problem stems from using an out-dated join syntax which is known to be error-prone. Use explicit joins instead! In your subquery you get data from shows and episodes. You cross join these tables by using `FROM shows, episodes` instead of joining them properly with `FROM shows JOIN episodes ON ...`. You then have `shows.id = episodes.showId` in your WHERE clause. But you need *two* criteria on ShowId: ...

Comment: one to filter the two crossed-joined tables (the criteria that would belong in the join's ON clause) and one to link the subquery to the outer query. If you had used proper joins you would have noticed that converting my `last_watched.showid = series.showid` would result in `episodes.showid = episodes.showid` in your query, which makes no sense. So you'd have to use a table alias to show whether you are talking about the inner or outer episodes. Then why do you join shows to episodes at all? All information needed is present in table episodes alone.

Comment: It is also an error to use '01001' instead of '00000' in your inner query. If a show had never been watched you would suggest to start *after* '01001', which is incorrect. But why did you make this fiddle at all? What about *your* system? Did you use my query in your SQLite system? Did it work or did you get an error? I've used your fiddle's setup and made a SQL Server fiddle. I consider SQL Sever closer to SQLite than MySQL. Here my query works with only slight adjustments: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27405/10.

Comment: Thanks for your working solution. I've just changed ```episode.*,
    substr('000' || season, -3, 3) || substr('000' || episode, -3, 3) as sortkey``` for ```sortKey as sortkey```now that I stored in the DB and I don't need to generate it.